# How to handle a request for data that is not yet ready

Tags: design-patterns, client-server

I have a server that accepts JSON requests. This server connects to various API's, collects data and arranges it based on the client request.

If a client requests data, but I am still in the process of downloading/manipulating required data from another API from the server, then what is the best way to handle this ?

Right now I can think of two options;

1. Wait until the data is ready, and then send the response.
2. Tell the client it is not ready yet and to try again soon (in 5-10
   seconds).

Which one of these would be more appropriate ? Is there a standard way of dealing with this situation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Cant you serve the client with stale data? In this case you could serve your client with available data, when you finish building current data you replace some common point and new requests are served with this new data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would rather have a very short delay before being given some indication that data would be available in a while than just have nothing happen, (my preference), if it is a web client you can return a page with an auto-refresh setting.

My reasoning is that I am reassured that the server is working and I have a working connection rather than just not getting a reply, (for an indeterminate time).  You do need to clearly specify in your client API that a valid response is "Not Ready Yet come back in  ...."